# Blender Object Deletion Issue

Tags: modeling

I am new to blender and after deleting an object the reference images I placed in the scene disappear. I am also unable to select objects through the viewport.

Here is a link to a screen recording of the issue happening
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGc6b.jpg

Comment: This seems to be a some kind of a bug. I'm guessing from fact also navigation icons disappeared. Can you repeat this issue with a new blend (cube +reference image or something like that)? Or share your simplified blend with a minimum of objects that still produce this issue. What version of blender?